# Solving $xyt = 1000$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, contest-math

How many nonegative integer solutions (triples), $(x, y, t)$ exist for:

$$xyt = 1000$$

I found the prime factorization being,

$$1000 = 2^3 \cdot 5^3$$

Let $x = 2^{a} \cdot 3^{b}$, let $y = 2^{c} \cdot 3^{d}$, let $t = 2^{e} \cdot 3^{f}$.

It follows that,

$$a + c + e = 3$$

As well as:

$$b + d + f = 3$$

$3$ can be represented using $uuu$ where $u$ is a unit for $1$.

We have:

$$\overbrace{u}^{a} + \overbrace{u}^{c} + \overbrace{u}^{e}$$

Where each space between $+$ and another $+$ corresponds to a different variable.

The ways to arrange $+$ in the $5$ objects is:

$$\binom{5}{2}$$

Hence, the total number of solutions possible is:

$$\binom{5}{2}^2 = 100 \space \text{Posible triples.}$$

Comment: What is the question?  Are you asking for us to verify your solution?

Comment: The number is correct, and the Stars and Bars argument is well described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is correct and the Stars and Bars argument is well described.